# How do I make a spinning button with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

How do I make a button that rotates using the mouse and that gives me the value of how many degrees are pivoted (as in a car steering wheel)?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? There's plenty of information on this subject out there actually..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var degree = 0;
document.addEventListener("mousewheel", function(event) {
    if (event.wheelDelta == 120) {
        degree++;
    } else {
        degree--;
    }
    var button = document.querySelector("#button");
    button.style.transform = "rotate(" + degree + "deg)";
    button.style.mozTransform = "rotate(" + degree + "deg)";
    button.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(" + degree + "deg)";
})
```

Comment: Tnx for help! :D I try like this but doesn't work!Am I wrong something?
`
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
var degree = 0;
document.addEventListener("mousewheel", function(event) {
    if (event.wheelDelta == 120) {
     degree++;
 } else {
degree--;    }
var button = document.querySelector("#button");
button.style.transform = "rotate(" + degree + "deg)";
button.style.mozTransform = "rotate(" + degree + "deg)";
button.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(" + degree + "deg)";
})
</script>
</head><body><button>Simple</button></body></html> `

Comment: which browser do you use?